# Failing compile on a class in the UIKit, its got to be an easy one

Tags: iphone, xcode, class, selector

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this issue,  but.....

I get the message  `"Receiver type "UIAlertView'` for instance message does not declare method **initWithName**

.H looks like this

```
#import1   <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginUIViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>

-(IBAction) LoginButton;

@end
```

.M looks like this

```
 #import "LoginUIViewController.h"

@implementation LoginUIViewController

-(IBAction) LoginButton { 

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                   delegate:self
                                                    message:@"message"
                                          CancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Full of typos. Sure it does not compile.

Comment: I fixed the "<" in the code as you said it was not there and you added it for posting reasons, but there are still a lot of typos in your code, from `#import1` to the case (upper/lower case) of your method names etc. Besides, you don't respect the naming conventions of Cocoa (lower-camelCase for method names for example). And you didn't even wrote the code where you erroneously call `initWithName:` which triggers the warning. Please make some effort if you intend some answer.

Answer (score 0):

The method is `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`.  The parts need to be specified in that order and spelled correctly, including capitalization.